# Is it possible to reproduce a nested logit discrete choice model with a glm?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, choice-modeling, mlogit

I'm trying to understand if I can fit `mlogit`'s nested logit model using a different parametrization under the base `glm` procedure. Is that even possible?

Here's what I got so far:

Using a common example that we see in the mlogit documentation:

```r
library(mlogit)
#> Loading required package: dfidx
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dfidx'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(AER)
#> Loading required package: car
#> Loading required package: carData
#> Loading required package: lmtest
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Loading required package: sandwich
#> Loading required package: survival
library(tidyverse)
data("TravelMode", package = "AER")
TravelMode <- mlogit.data(
  TravelMode,
  choice = "choice", shape = "long", alt.var = "mode", chid.var = 
    "individual")


TravelMode$avinc <- with(TravelMode, (mode == "air") * income)
nl.TM <- mlogit(
  choice ~ wait + gcost + avinc, TravelMode,
  reflevel = "car",
  nests = list(fly = "air", ground = c("train", "bus", "car")),
  unscaled = TRUE
)
summary(nl.TM)
#> 
#> Call:
#> mlogit(formula = choice ~ wait + gcost + avinc, data = TravelMode, 
#>     reflevel = "car", nests = list(fly = "air", ground = c("train", 
#>         "bus", "car")), unscaled = TRUE)
#> 
#> Frequencies of alternatives:choice
#>     car     air   train     bus 
#> 0.28095 0.27619 0.30000 0.14286 
#> 
#> bfgs method
#> 17 iterations, 0h:0m:0s 
#> g'(-H)^-1g = 1.02E-07 
#> gradient close to zero 
#> 
#> Coefficients :
#>                    Estimate Std. Error z-value  Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept):air    6.042373   1.331325  4.5386 5.662e-06 ***
#> (Intercept):train  5.064620   0.676010  7.4919 6.795e-14 ***
#> (Intercept):bus    4.096325   0.628870  6.5138 7.328e-11 ***
#> wait              -0.112618   0.011826 -9.5232 < 2.2e-16 ***
#> gcost             -0.031588   0.007434 -4.2491 2.147e-05 ***
#> avinc              0.026162   0.019842  1.3185   0.18732    
#> iv:fly             0.586009   0.113056  5.1833 2.180e-07 ***
#> iv:ground          0.388962   0.157904  2.4633   0.01377 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Log-Likelihood: -193.66
#> McFadden R^2:  0.31753 
#> Likelihood ratio test : chisq = 180.21 (p.value = < 2.22e-16)
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now, some things pop into my head when I see the `mlogit` output. One is the lack of `car` as an intercept a clue that it is the reference category. Another is the nesting factors `iv:fly` and `iv:ground`. Could this indicate that the nesting factor interacts with the individual observations? I don't know but there is no indication in the `mlogit.data` function call. It seems more like a standard within the package to precede the nesting factors with `iv`.

Here is my attempt using `glm` but its way of:

```r
library(mlogit)
#> Loading required package: dfidx
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dfidx'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(AER)
#> Loading required package: car
#> Loading required package: carData
#> Loading required package: lmtest
#> Loading required package: zoo
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'zoo'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     as.Date, as.Date.numeric
#> Loading required package: sandwich
#> Loading required package: survival
library(tidyverse)
data("TravelMode", package = "AER")
df = as_tibble(TravelMode)
df %>% 
  mutate(mode = relevel(mode, ref='car'), 
         nest_ = if_else(mode == 'air', 'fly', 'ground')
         ) %>% 
glm(choice~ mode + wait + gcost + I(mode == 'air'):income + nest_, family = binomial(link = 'logit'), data=.) %>%
  summary
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = choice ~ mode + wait + gcost + I(mode == "air"):income + 
#>     nest_, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = .)
#> 
#> Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
#>                                Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)                  -0.7638322  0.2954621  -2.585  0.00973 ** 
#> modeair                       5.4437064  0.8455117   6.438 1.21e-10 ***
#> modetrain                     3.6947145  0.4357960   8.478  < 2e-16 ***
#> modebus                       3.0335691  0.4593991   6.603 4.02e-11 ***
#> wait                         -0.1051971  0.0109887  -9.573  < 2e-16 ***
#> gcost                        -0.0009074  0.0020019  -0.453  0.65036    
#> nest_ground                          NA         NA      NA       NA    
#> I(mode == "air")FALSE:income -0.0026141  0.0053432  -0.489  0.62467    
#> I(mode == "air")TRUE:income   0.0201562  0.0099694   2.022  0.04319 *  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 944.72  on 839  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 758.36  on 832  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 774.36
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

But the nesting factor doesn't make sense, since its completely determined by the choice set. What else could I try?

<sup>Created on 2024-01-30 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I wanted to mention as well that at some point it makes sense to try and compare direct predictions, since parameters might be different, but the underlying model is the same.